# Como puedo insertar un div en un listado

Tags: javascript, wordpress

quería saber cómo insertar por ejemplo un div en un sitio random en un listado, digamos tengo una web que ofrece un listado de ofertas de trabajo, pero donde se demuestra listado de ofertas fe trabajo, en algún sitio entre dichas ofertas aparezca empresas o anuncios.

No quiero insertarlo manualmente por que va aparecer cuando hay un loop debajo de cada oferta de trabajo, solo quiero que aparezca dos veces o solo una vez en un sitio random entre las ofertas.

Un saludo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías dentro del while crear un contador e incrementarlo con cada vez que el loop complete una posición, entonces podrías agregar tu código basado en la posición del loop, algo así:

```
if (have_posts()): 

    $counter = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        if ( $counter == 2 ) {
            // Tu codigo aqui
        }

    $counter++; endif;

endwhile;
```